# GCP Find users' location within it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I really need some help?

In my company we need to check if one of our users is using GCP outside of the location they told us. Is there a way for me to find out which country or get this person's IP via GCP Console?

Thanks,

Comment: The answer by Serhii is probably as close as you can get for most users. There are several methods to bypass detecting a user's real location. The simplest is a home-based VPN. There are also several factors that can cause false positives.

Answer (score 2):

You can find such information by following the documentation page [Login audit log](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/4580120?hl=en):

1. Open the Google Admin console.
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to Reports.
3. On the left, under Audit log, click Login.

> The Login audit log provides the following information:
>
> - **IP address**: IP address that the user used to sign in. Usually the address is the user's physical location, but it can be a proxy server or a Virtual Private Network (VPN) address.